# Golang how do you crop a circular image out of a rectangular jpeg.

Tags: go, jpeg

In Golang how do you crop a circular image out of a rectangular jpeg. The rectangle can vary in size. If you have an image.Image would you crop out a circle from the center of the image where the circle takes up as much space as possible? I want to keep the circle and remove the rest.

Answer (score 7):

This example using the drawing package from the golang blog should do roughly what you want;

```
type circle struct {
    p image.Point
    r int
}

func (c *circle) ColorModel() color.Model {
    return color.AlphaModel
}

func (c *circle) Bounds() image.Rectangle {
    return image.Rect(c.p.X-c.r, c.p.Y-c.r, c.p.X+c.r, c.p.Y+c.r)
}

func (c *circle) At(x, y int) color.Color {
    xx, yy, rr := float64(x-c.p.X)+0.5, float64(y-c.p.Y)+0.5, float64(c.r)
    if xx*xx+yy*yy < rr*rr {
        return color.Alpha{255}
    }
    return color.Alpha{0}
}

    draw.DrawMask(dst, dst.Bounds(), src, image.ZP, &circle{p, r}, image.ZP, draw.Over)
```

Note that it takes a rectangle and masks everything but the circle beginning at point `p` with radius `r`. The full article can be found here http://blog.golang.org/go-imagedraw-package

In your case you would like the mask to just be your normal background and the src to be the currently rectangular image you'd like to use part of.

Comment: Based on your idea: https://goplay.space/#_RTH0rWA7Ae